# No python facet available to add to an Intellij project even though a 3.10 SDK has been configured?

Tags: intellij-idea

A `python3.10` SDK is configured:

[image]

But then it can not be added as a facet to the current project?

[image]

[image]

I am on the `IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.4 (Ultimate Edition)`  `macOS 13.4.1`   `Non-Bundled Plugins:    Pythonid (231.9225.16)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what happened:

- In my first pass at adding an existing python sdk an incorrect path was supplied
- After correcting the path apparently the SDK was only *partially* updated inside Intellij project metadata

I re-added the existing python installation to Intellij [this time ensuring there were no errors] and it did work.